# Como verificar se o Graph API do Facebook está ou não retornando uma imagem?

Tags: php, facebook

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que usa a foto de usuário como a foto de perfil do facebook, mas alguns usuários não tem perfil do facebook, logo o Graph API retorna erro e não retorna uma imagem, qual função posso usar para verificar se o url do Graph API está ou não retornando uma imagem?

Answer (score 1):

**Gustavo**, já trabalhei com OpenGraph, segue abaixo um exemplo que fiz:

```
<?php

$user_id = 'SociedadeFemininaOficial';
//$user_id = 'UsuarioErrado';

try
{
    $user_photo = @file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{$user_id}/picture?redirect=false");

    if(strpos($http_response_header[0], "200") === FALSE)
    {
        // usuário não contém foto ou não deu permissão para tal
        echo "Usuário não contém foto ou não deu permissão para tal";
    }
    else
    {
        $user_photo = json_decode($user_photo);
        echo $user_photo->data->url;
    }
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    throw new Exception($ex);
}
```

**Obs.:** Ao invés de `file_get_contents` você também pode utilizar `cURL` para receber os dados. Basta checar o status do http doce.